# how to clear all NSUserDefaults values in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am using **NSUserDefaults** lots of time in my app to store some values, but on "refresh button" i want to clear all stored values, Is there any way to clear all NSUserDefaults values?

Answer (score 14):

You can remove all stored value using below code see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) for more details

```
- (void)removeUserDefaults 
{
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary * dict = [userDefaults dictionaryRepresentation];
    for (id key in dict) {
        [userDefaults removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Or in shortest way

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:[NSDictionary dictionary] forName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```

**Swift**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.forEach { (key) in
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
}
```

Comment: The single-line solution did not work for me.  However, the removeUserDefaults() function did the job.

Answer (score 5):

You can clear your user defaults by using following statements -

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

You can call a selector on the refresh button and keep the above statements in it, as-

```
- (void) refreshUserDefaults
{
    NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
}
```

Comment: Your second option isn't valid here and makes it seem you have misunderstood the question. This isn't what was being asked they specifically state that the `NSUserDefaults` to be cleared when pressing the reset button, how would pressing the reset button in there app make 2 happen?

Comment: No worries at least you saw your mistake